# Ruby: Sorting an array with another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, object, activerecord

let `o1, o2, o3, o4` activerecord objects with

- `o1.kind = "att2"`
- `o2.kind = "att3"`
- `o3.kind = "att4"`
- `o4.kind = "att1"`

Let `a = [o1, o2, o3, o4]`

Let `b = ['att1', 'att3', 'att4', 'att2']`

I need to sort `a` with `b` so that the new order in `a` becomes:

```
a = [o4, o2, o3, o1]
```

I tried

```
a.sort_by do |element|
  b.index(element)
end
```

But how to sort by `kind?`

Comment: `b.index(element).kind` ?

Comment: `a`, `b` are pretty bad names, even for an example, specially considering they are collections (so plural is more meaningful).

Comment: Please don't select an answer so quickly, give time for people to improve their answers. Instead, give some feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O(n+m):

```
Hash[a.map { |o| [o.kind, o] }].values_at(*b)
```

Comment: I prefer this implementation even though it's slightly less pretty, since it is going to be O(n).

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Is this pretty enough? `a.mash { |o| [o.kind, o] }.values_at(*b)`

Comment: I just mean that `sort_by` is self-descriptive, while this form is less obvious that it's supposed to be a sort.

Comment: What the OP wants isn't really a sort, it's an associative lookup. I think the OP didn't know that though.

Comment: @theTinMan: Good point. I think the most declarative code for this associative lookup could be a slightly modified version using a new abstraction: `a.to_hash_by(&:kind).values_at(*b)` or something similar, `categorize_by`?.

Answer (score 6):

You need the index of `element.kind`, not `element`.

```
a.sort_by do |element|
  b.index(element.kind)
end
```

Comment: +1 for simple, -1 for O(n^2)

Comment: The `O(n^2)` aspect is critical if this is going to be running against large sets of values for `a` and/or `b`, because it will cause it to run increasingly slower.

Comment: fair enough...good point :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using OpenStruct to imitate an Active Record result:

```
require 'ostruct'
o1, o2, o3, o4 = [*(1..4)].map{ OpenStruct.new }

o1.kind = "att2"
o2.kind = "att3"
o3.kind = "att4"
o4.kind = "att1"

a = [o1, o2, o3, o4]
b = ['att1', 'att3', 'att4', 'att2']

a_hash = Hash[a.map{ |e| [e.kind, e] }]
a_hash # => {"att2"=>#<OpenStruct kind="att2">, "att3"=>#<OpenStruct kind="att3">, "att4"=>#<OpenStruct kind="att4">, "att1"=>#<OpenStruct kind="att1">}

new_a_order = a_hash.values_at(*b)
new_a_order # => [#<OpenStruct kind="att1">, #<OpenStruct kind="att3">, #<OpenStruct kind="att4">, #<OpenStruct kind="att2">]
```

---

Benchmark time:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'ostruct'

o1, o2, o3, o4 = [*(1..4)].map{ OpenStruct.new }

o1.kind = "att2"
o2.kind = "att3"
o3.kind = "att4"
o4.kind = "att1"

a = [o1, o2, o3, o4]
b = ['att1', 'att3', 'att4', 'att2']

def tokland(a_ary, b_ary)
  Hash[a_ary.map{ |e| [e.kind, e] }].values_at(*b_ary)
end

def bioneurlanet(a_ary, b_ary)
  b_ary.map { |att| a_ary.detect { |obj| obj.kind == att } }
end

def mihai(a_ary, b_ary)
  a_ary.sort_by do |element|
    b_ary.index(element.kind)
  end
end

N = 1_000_000
puts 'Ruby => ' + RUBY_VERSION
puts 'N => %d' % N

print 'tokland => ', tokland(a,b), "\n"
print 'bioneurlanet => ', bioneurlanet(a,b), "\n"
print 'mihai => ', mihai(a,b), "\n"


Benchmark.bm(12) do |x|
  x.report('tokland') { N.times { tokland(a,b) }}
  x.report('bioneurlanet') { N.times { bioneurlanet(a,b) }}
  x.report('mihai') { N.times { mihai(a,b) }}
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Ruby => 2.0.0
N => 1000000
tokland => [#<OpenStruct kind="att1">, #<OpenStruct kind="att3">, #<OpenStruct kind="att4">, #<OpenStruct kind="att2">]
bioneurlanet => [#<OpenStruct kind="att1">, #<OpenStruct kind="att3">, #<OpenStruct kind="att4">, #<OpenStruct kind="att2">]
mihai => [#<OpenStruct kind="att1">, #<OpenStruct kind="att3">, #<OpenStruct kind="att4">, #<OpenStruct kind="att2">]
                   user     system      total        real
tokland        2.890000   0.010000   2.900000 (  2.885242)
bioneurlanet   4.430000   0.000000   4.430000 (  4.434342)
mihai          3.180000   0.010000   3.190000 (  3.189240)
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use `sort_by`, but it gets the result you want. Just a different way to think about the problem.

```
b.map { |att| a.detect { |obj| obj.kind == att } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a hash instead of an array for sorting:

```
b = {"att1"=>0, "att3"=>1, "att4"=>2, "att2"=>3}
a.sort_by { |e| b[e.kind] }
```

This is both, fast and plain.

You can convert an existing array with `Hash[ary.each_with_index.to_a]`

Comment: Yes, using the right container from the start really helps.